# use tikz to draw indicator line

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How to use tikz to draw the indicator line in the figure

```
\begin{document}
    this is a text
    
    this is a text this is a text this is a text
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. In this specfic case the  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) should show how you are creating the text part as thta may have an impact on exactly how the drawing needs to be done.

Comment: For instance, if the text is place as part of a `tikz` in a `tikzpcture` then the drawing is fairly easy. Otherwise another package such as `tikzmark` will be needed.

Comment: I know nothing about complex tikz. I just need a code that can be compiled

Comment: @eric Did you try with tikzmark as Peter Grill suggested above? You can search for its usage in this forum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your code fragment and showed image we can only guess about context of your image. Id this part of text in your document? is this part of some image?

In case of text, as mentioned @Peter Grill, use of the `tikzmark` library can be a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
this is a \tikzmarknode{a}{text}

\bigskip
this is a text this is a text this is a \tikzmarknode{b}{text}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw ([xshift=1em] a -| b.east) -- ++ (1em,0) 
            |- ([xshift=1em] b.east) coordinate[pos=0.25] (c);
    \draw[->]  (c) -- ++ (1em,0) node[right] {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

after at least two compilation you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much